# Error when processing concurrent events in WSO2 BPEL

Tags: wso2, bpel

I developed a BPEL workflow using WSO2 BPS. That workflow has two event handlers for two different kinds of events.

The workflow works fine if it receives two events (of to different kinds) sequentially. However if there are two events that arrive at the same time, it seem that one of them is processed and the other one has to wait and then I saw a timed-out exception (for the waiting event).

Any body has experiences with this? Is there any solution to have the two event processed concurrently?

eventHandler:

```
<bpel:onEvent messageType="ws-dpalert:pushIn" operation="pushAlert" partnerLink="alertCallbackEvent" portType="ws-dpalert:PushPortType" variable="alertMessage">
    <bpel:correlations>
        <bpel:correlation initiate="no" set="correlator"/>
    </bpel:correlations>
    <bpel:scope name="onlertMessages">
        <bpel:sequence name="alertProcessing">                                         
                            ...........                                
        </bpel:sequence>
    </bpel:scope>
</bpel:onEvent>
```

Thanks,

Minh Tri.

---

My event handlers are:

....................

```
                        </bpel:sequence>
    </bpel:scope>
</bpel:onEvent>
<bpel:onEvent messageType="ws-dpalert:pushIn" operation="pushAlert" partnerLink="alertCallbackEvent" portType="ws-dpalert:PushPortType" variable="alertMessage">
    <bpel:correlations>
        <bpel:correlation initiate="no" set="correlator"/>
    </bpel:correlations>
    <bpel:scope name="onlertMessages">
        <bpel:sequence name="alertProcessing">                                       

                            ...........                             

                    </bpel:sequence>
    </bpel:scope>
</bpel:onEvent>
```

Comment: Can you post the event handlers?